# How to calculate the total resistance of the 5-cell (4 dimensional pyramid)?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, symmetry, electrical-resistance

The total resistance of an electrical circuit with the shape of a triangle or pyramid is easy to find.
Each edge has the resistance (value is R)

How can I find the total resistance of the 5-cell (4 dimensional pyramid)

Comment: You need to provide more information anyway. Show an example of circuit for instance

Comment: Another edit is pending, but here is a [graph of a 5-cell](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b9/4-simplex_t0.svg/120px-4-simplex_t0.svg.png) that has been flattened to 2D. Each of the five vertices connects to all 4 other vertices, and crossings of edges shown in this 2D map should be ignored. OP is asking that if each edge that connects two vertices was a resistor with value R, what is the effective resistance of the total circuit.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the article:

> Severino V. Gervacio, ["Resistance distance in complete $n$-partite graphs"](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0166218X15004783), Disc. App. Math. **203**, pp. 53–61

the author cites the surprising and elegant result (see refs. [3, 7, 9] therein) that

> [F]or a connected graph, the summation of effective resistances between all pairs of adjacent vertices is equal to the total number of vertices minus 1.

This assumes a resistance of 1 (dimensionless) along each edge of the graph;  for a resistance of $R$ along each graph, we simply multiply the result of this theorem by $R$.

For a complete graph on $n$ vertices (which is the same as the skeleton of the $n$-cell), this implies that the total of all resistances of adjacent pairs of vertices is $n-1$.  Since all pairs of vertices are adjacent in a complete graph, there are $n(n-1)/2$ pairs of adjacent vertices, and so the resistance between any pair of adjacent vertices is $2/n$ (or $2R/n$ if the resistance of each edge is $R$.)